# What's the best practice for transferring huge binary files with ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, binary, data-transfer

Consider an ASP.NET page with this code:

```
while (read)
{
   Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
   Response.Flush();
}
```

The application should be highly performance-tuned and handle thousands on concurrent requests and the main purpose is transferring huge binary file to clients over high speed connections. I can do the job with an `ASP.NET page`, with `HTTP Handler`, `IHttpAsyncHandler`, `ISAPI filter` and ...

The question is what is the best choice for this purpose ?

Comment: Binary data is received from other server via socket

Comment: The process is not CPU bounded but because it's lengthy, under stress test ASP.NET starves (no more thread is leaved in the pool) so clients get time out while there is enough CPU & RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the page is liable to be I/O bound then I'd go the Async road. But you should use the asynchronous read methods (if available) on your `Stream` object as well.

For more information see:

> [FileStream Constructor - with async example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7db28s3c.aspx)

To address your comment that you receive this data via a socket, you'll also find that most of the `System.Net.Sockets` namespace classes support asynchronous behaviour.

Comment: As I researched ISAPI filters are the fastest way but I don't know if it's possible to write one with C# and if yes, do I have any access to asp.net features like calling a webservice, etc...

Comment: @xaqron - what version of IIS are you on?

Comment: No limitation. I can use IIS 7.0 as it's my choice now. please check the comment I added to question.

Comment: @Xaqron - you don't need an ISAPI filter for this. You just need to manage your ASP.NET threads better so they're not blocking reading data from the source socket and writing to the output stream. Using Async techniques is how to achieve this.

Comment: I found an article about Async handler usage on MSDN which targets the same problem I already have (client timeout while no reurce shortage is seen -> asp.net pool saturation). But afetre reading it I have a new question. would you please take a look at it:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893215/how-to-configure-asp-net-thread-count-upper-limit-based-on-system-resources